# Power BI - Grouping and Summing Data by Date Filt

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I need some help with grouping data and running calculations with date filters. Here is the original data, and I would like to add some the calculation of the gross pay (Reg Pay+Bonus Pay), total hours (Reg Hours+OT Hours), and Actual Hourly Rate (gross pay / total hours).

| First Name | Check Date | Reg Pay | Bonus Pay | Reg Hour | OT Hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 12/1/2023 | 175 |  | 2 | 1 |
| A | 12/7/2023 | 225 | 500 | 3 | 1 |
| A | 12/14/2023 | 175 |  | 2 | 1 |
| B | 12/1/2023 | 175 |  | 2 | 1 |
| B | 12/7/2023 | 275 | 100 | 4 | 1 |
| B | 12/14/2023 | 375 |  | 5 | 1 |

What I need is, if I set the date range from 12/1/2023 to 12/14/2023, it will group first name, sum Reg Pay, Bonus Pay, Reg Hour, and OT Hours, then do the calculation of gross pay and total hours, then run the calculation for the actual hourly rate.

I added Gross Pay, Total Hours and Actual Hourly Rate as a new column, please see below.

```
Gross Pay = Payroll_Journal[Reg Pay]+Payroll_Journal[OT Pay]
```

```
Total Hours = Payroll_Journal[Reg Hours]+Payroll_Journal[OT Hours]
```

```
Actual Hourly Rate = IFERROR(Payroll_Journal[Gross Pay]/Payroll_Journal[Total Hours],0)
```

However, this is my return result, which is returning the sum from each paycheck's actual hourly rate.

| First Name | Reg Pay | Bonus Pay | Reg Hour | OT Hours | Gross Pay | Total Hours | Actual Hourly Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 575 | 500 | 7 | 3 | 1075 | 10 | 297.92 |
| B | 825 | 100 | 11 | 3 | 725 | 14 | 162.5 |

I am hoping to get the following result, is it possible?

| First Name | Reg Pay | Bonus Pay | Reg Hour | OT Hours | Gross Pay | Total Hours | Actual Hourly Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 575 | 500 | 7 | 3 | 1075 | 10 | 107.50 |
| B | 825 | 100 | 11 | 3 | 725 | 14 | 51.79 |

Answer (score 0):

This solved! Turns out I need to set the Actual Hourly Rate calculation as a measurement instead of a column. :)